# Angular UI uibModal - how to make transparent

Tags: angularjs, dialog, modal-dialog, transparency

Is it possible in uibModal to make the surroundings (outside the modal) transparent so that the underneath layer is seen?
As stated at the doc [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), I've tried using windowTopClass property but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use `backdrop: false` in your modal configuration or add additional CSS classes with the `backdropClass` property.
Here's a Plunker, demonstrating this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/oqkRkmnVk0gptEfcqoVI?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I dont think `uibModal` offers that kind of service, you can try to set `CSS` property on the `HTML` parts after `modal` is opened :

```
     $scope.open = function (size) {
        //call a function that sets CSS property to transparent        
        $scope.setCSSTotransparent();
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
          size: size,
          resolve: {
            items: function () {
              return $scope.items;
            }
          }
        });
```